# Open Location Settings Android with QT

Tags: android, c++, qt, location

How can I open the location settings from android via Qt?

I have already tried this and I can open the settings successfully, but not the location settings:

```
QAndroidJniObject intent("android/content/Intent","()V");
    if ( intent.isValid() )
    {
        QAndroidJniObject param1 = QAndroidJniObject::fromString("com.android.settings");
        QAndroidJniObject param2 = QAndroidJniObject::fromString("com.android.settings.Settings");

        if ( param1.isValid() && param2.isValid() )
        {
            intent.callObjectMethod("setClassName","(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/content/Intent;",param1.object<jobject>(),param2.object<jobject>());

            activity.callObjectMethod("startActivity","(Landroid/content/Intent;)V",intent.object<jobject>());
        }
    }
```

I even have changed the param2 to "android.settings.LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS" as it is written on the Android Developer page - but without any success.

Does anybody know how to do that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found a solution!**

```
QAndroidJniObject activity = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod("org/qtproject/qt5/android/QtNative", "activity", "()Landroid/app/Activity;");
if ( activity.isValid() )
{
    qDebug() << "activity.isValid()";
    QAndroidJniObject param = QAndroidJniObject::fromString("android.settings.LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS");

    if (param.isValid() )
    {
        QAndroidJniObject intent("android/content/Intent","(Ljava/lang/String;)V", param.object<jstring>());
        activity.callObjectMethod("startActivity","(Landroid/content/Intent;)V",intent.object<jobject>());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
QAndroidJniObject activity = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod("org/qtproject/qt5/android/QtNative", "activity", "()Landroid/app/Activity;");
if ( activity.isValid() )
{
     QAndroidJniObject param = QAndroidJniObject::fromString("android.settings.LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS");

     if (param.isValid() )
     {
           QAndroidJniObject intent("android/content/Intent","(Ljava/lang/String;)V", param.object<jstring>());
           activity.callMethod<void>("startActivity","(Landroid/content/Intent;)V", intent.object<jobject>());
     }
 }
```